# Laravel 'sail up' does not work on production server

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am not sure if I can use laravel sail in production. First question is, can I use laravel sail in production?

And if I can, how can I use laravel sail in production? I am trying to deploy a website using laravel sail. But when I try to execute `sail up` command, it says `Docker is not running`. But when I check `systemctl status docker`, it says `Docker is running`.
What do I need to do?

Comment: Could it be that you need sudo privileges for commands like `docker ps`?

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with sudo access. I created a default docker image droplet from Digital Ocean and I had problem with sudo access. I could not solve the problem and then installed docker on a fresh Ubuntu 20.4 LTS and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Sail is a development environment so I don't think it's meant for production.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Docker cannot start on Windows

cmd

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
```

power shell

```
 & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```